# The SMTP server requires a secure connection from MVC App on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp, gmail

I am using below code to send email from my MVC 5 app  and is  sending emails while running locally from visual studio , but not sending mails when I try to send from the server (shared windows hosting)

```
 public ActionResult TestMail()
    {
        try
        {
            string email_from = "email_from@gmail.com";
            string email_to = "email_to@gmail.com";
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress(email_from);
                mail.To.Add(email_to);

                mail.Subject = "Reference form Id:" ;
                mail.Body = "<h1>Test Body </h1>";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                Attachment data = new Attachment(
                               Server.MapPath("~/JsonData/privacystatement.pdf"),
                               System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                mail.Attachments.Add(data);

                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email_from@gmail.com", "passcode");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
                ViewBag.Message = "Email sent.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Email not sent Error." + ex.Message;
        }

        return View("Finish");
    }
```

I am getting this error from server

```
    Email not sent Error.The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.
```

My current account  Settings :

```
    Less secure app access ON 
    Two factor Authentication (SMS on phone etc) DISABLED
```

While running locally this code is working and email is successfully sent but while upload code to server , then  only  i am getting this error

Should I add some more properties to ensure this will run on the server (shared windows hosting) as well

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @PK No and now i swithced my solution to send using Sendgrid \

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 aspects.

One is the code itself. I create a SmtpClient like that:

```
new SmtpClient
{
    Port = 587,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    EnableSsl = true,
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",

    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailFrom, password)
};
```

Second is setting the Gmail account to allow such actions. You will have to set it up in that Gmail account.
Please refer to this resource https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

It contains a simple step-by-step instruction to do that.

After this, my code sends emails through Gmail from app hosted on standard windows hosting provider without problems.